# Archive Template being used instead of Category Template for Custom Post Type

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, templates, archives

I have a Custom Post Type created, that has its own Custom Taxonomy that give the Posts their own Categorys. I am currently building the Templates.

The Custom Post Type has the slug `service`, and the Custom Taxonomy has the slug `service-category`. I have created the template file `archive-service.php`, and that works fine, but when I try to go into one of the Categories created (and listed) from what is there, it uses the template `archive.php`, and when I do `var_dump(get_post_type())`, I get `service`. I have the template  `archive-service-category.php`, `category-service.php` and `category-service-category.php`, but I still get the same `archive.php` template being used.

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong, or what I have overlooked?

Answer (score 1):

Just found out how to fix it, but I will leave the question here for others.

I simply needed to create the file `taxonomy-service-category.php`, and now it is working fine